# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rightAnswer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

İ want to use [this codepen pen](https://codepen.io/savant/pen/gbaveO) with 4 options, and i edited js code, at first few answers it working fine but after few question ı get this error. The problem is my 4 options. Because its work fine with 3 options.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rightAnswer' of undefined
>       at checkAnswer (index.js:1113)
>       at answerA_clicked (index.js:1082)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:204) *(this is answer button)*

Codepen JS

```js
 //variables
var quiz = [];
quiz[0] = new Question("What is 1/4 of 100?", "25", "24", "23");
quiz[1] = new Question("What color is blood?", "Red", "White", "Green");
quiz[2] = new Question("What color is grass?", "Green", "White", "Red");
quiz[3] = new Question("How many legs does a spider have?", "8", "6", "4");
quiz[4] = new Question("Who is the king of the Netherlands?", "Willem-Alexander", "Willem-Alexzelf", "Willem-Alexniemand");
quiz[5] = new Question("What is 2-2?", "0", "2", "4");
quiz[6] = new Question("What was Vincent van Gogh?", "Artist", "Baker", "Jobless");
var randomQuestion;
var answers = [];
var currentScore = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  btnProvideQuestion();
});

function Question(question,rightAnswer,wrongAnswer1,wrongAnswer2) {
    this.question = question;
    this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    this.wrongAnswer1 = wrongAnswer1;
    this.wrongAnswer2 = wrongAnswer2;
};

function shuffle(o) {
 for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
 return o;
};

function btnProvideQuestion() { 
  
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*quiz.length);
 randomQuestion = quiz[randomNumber]; //getQuestion
  answers = [randomQuestion.rightAnswer, randomQuestion.wrongAnswer1, randomQuestion.wrongAnswer2];
  shuffle(answers);
  
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML= randomQuestion.question;
  document.getElementById("answerA").value= answers[0];
  document.getElementById("answerA").innerHTML= answers[0];
  document.getElementById("answerB").value= answers[1];
  document.getElementById("answerB").innerHTML= answers[1];
  document.getElementById("answerC").value= answers[2];
  document.getElementById("answerC").innerHTML= answers[2];

}

function answerA_clicked() {
  var answerA = document.getElementById("answerA").value;
   checkAnswer(answerA);
}

function answerB_clicked() {
  var answerB = document.getElementById("answerB").value;
  checkAnswer(answerB);
}
function answerC_clicked() {
  var answerC = document.getElementById("answerC").value;
   
  checkAnswer(answerC);
}

function adjustScore(isCorrect) {
  debugger;
  if (isCorrect) {
    currentScore++;
  } else {
    if (currentScore > 0) {
      currentScore--;
   }
  }
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = currentScore;
}

function checkAnswer(answer) {  
  if (answer == randomQuestion.rightAnswer) {
    adjustScore(true);
    btnProvideQuestion();
  } else { 
    alert("Loser!");
    adjustScore(false);
  }   
}
```

and thats my edited js  (İ wanted to add false score, so WScore is about false score)

```js
var quiz = [];
....
....
...[note: So many question in here]
quiz[1187] = new Question("Vincent van Gogh", "1853", "1859", "1844", "1841");

var randomQuestion;
var answers = [];
var currentScore = 0;
var currentWScore = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  btnProvideQuestion();
});

function Question(question,rightAnswer,wrongAnswer1,wrongAnswer2,wrongAnswer3) {
    this.question = question;
    this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    this.wrongAnswer1 = wrongAnswer1;
    this.wrongAnswer2 = wrongAnswer2;
    this.wrongAnswer3 = wrongAnswer3;
};

function shuffle(o) {
 for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
 return o;
};

function btnProvideQuestion() { 
  
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*quiz.length);
 randomQuestion = quiz[randomNumber]; //getQuestion
  answers = [randomQuestion.rightAnswer, randomQuestion.wrongAnswer1, randomQuestion.wrongAnswer2, randomQuestion.wrongAnswer3];
  shuffle(answers);
  
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML= randomQuestion.question;
  document.getElementById("answerA").value= answers[0];
  document.getElementById("answerA").innerHTML= answers[0];
  document.getElementById("answerB").value= answers[1];
  document.getElementById("answerB").innerHTML= answers[1];
  document.getElementById("answerC").value= answers[2];
  document.getElementById("answerC").innerHTML= answers[2];
  document.getElementById("answerD").value= answers[3];
  document.getElementById("answerD").innerHTML= answers[3];

}

function answerA_clicked() {
  var answerA = document.getElementById("answerA").value;
[1082 LİNE]   checkAnswer(answerA);
}

function answerB_clicked() {
  var answerB = document.getElementById("answerB").value;
  checkAnswer(answerB);
}
function answerC_clicked() {
  var answerC = document.getElementById("answerC").value;
   
  checkAnswer(answerC);
}
function answerD_clicked() {
  var answerD = document.getElementById("answerD").value;
   
  checkAnswer(answerD);
}

function adjustScore(isCorrect) {
  debugger;
  if (isCorrect) {
    currentScore++;
  } else {
    currentWScore++;
  }
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = currentScore;
  document.getElementById("Wscore").innerHTML = currentWScore;
}

[1113 LİNE] function checkAnswer(answer) {  

  if (answer == randomQuestion.rightAnswer) {
   swal({
      title: "Right!",
   type: "success",
   allowOutsideClick: "on",
   timer: "850",
   showConfirmButton: false,
      html: true
});
 adjustScore(true);
    btnProvideQuestion();
  } 
  else { 
    if (checkoutHistory.checked) {
    swal({
      title: "Wrong",
      type: "error",
      confirmButtonColor: "#3498db",
      confirmButtonText: "Next",
      customClass: "sweetAlertModal",
   allowOutsideClick: "on",
      html: true
});
    adjustScore(false);
    btnProvideQuestion();
  } else { 
    swal({
      title: "Wrong!",
      type: "error",
      confirmButtonColor: "#3498db",
      confirmButtonText: "Next",
      customClass: "sweetAlertModal",
      html: true
});
    adjustScore(false);
    btnProvideQuestion();
  }   
  }   
}
```

Comment: Which means your `randomQuestion` is undefined at a point and also if you have 4 options, where is the 4th one in your code `quiz[0] = new Question("What is 1/4 of 100?", "25", "24", "23");`

Comment: there are not my question. ı am changed my questions with codepen questions. Because in my js file will be so long.

for example my question:
quiz[1187] = new Question("Vincent van Gogh", "1853", "1859", "1844", "1841");

Comment: I updated the code pen with 4 options. Check and let me know https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/rrYpbm

Comment: This code doesn't different from my js code? So it's not working...

İ think we need to change this line;

function shuffle(o) {
 for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
 return o;
};

Comment: Check the codependent..it have 4 options..this is what you need?